# Defining "<" and ">" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am a freshman in high-school who has some time on his hands, and I decided it would be beneficial to write some programs that demonstrate what commonly used functions do.  I have always wondered what exactly goes into the greater than and less than operators, so I have set out to define them by myself.  The only roadblock that I have encountered is how one can assert that a value is negative or positive, without using the greater than or less than operators.  So far, I have something that looks like this:

```
a = 34
b = 42
c = a - b
puts "A is Greater than B" while is_positive?(c)
```

Does anybody have ideas on how I would define `is_positive?(c)`?

Comment: The CPU does the arithmetics for you, so the question doesn't really make a lot of sense. Maybe what you want is to implement arithmetics yourself, in which case you'd have to work with a raw (probably binary) representation of the numbers

Comment: So there is no way to assert that a number is positive or negative without using the < or > operators?  And anyways, I want to know how the CPU does it, no matter how deep and dirty it becomes :)

Comment: Not if you don't have access to the raw binary representation. I think these low-level mechanisms are easier to explore with a programming language that is closer to the metal, like C or even raw assembly, where you can do stuff like checking the sign bit or something. What the `cmp` instruction on x86 does is subtract the numbers and check the carry flag

Comment: So the answer to this 'problem' is out of the scope of Ruby?

Comment: I think you'd have to define exactly what you want to learn. If you want to know how a CPU works, than Ruby won't get you very far

Comment: Because it is basically a VM, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This question should not be tagged ruby but mathematics.
2. Then you absolutely do need the equality operator.
3. If you want to restrict yourself to just the `+` and `-` operators, you have no other way of deciding whether `a` or `b` is greater, than to count up from 0 and see which value you hit first (which of course is tested using the equality operator)

Comment: If he want to know what is grater than (s)he should write this i.e. `diff = a - b; puts "A is greater or equal to B" if diff == diff.abs`

Comment: `abs` is quite an extension of the set of operators compared to only `+`, `-` and `==`. Thats why I dont think he wants to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean operator `<=>` that return `-1` first argument is less, `0` if equal and `1` if greater than second? Or maybe you mean [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) that return `-1` if argument is less than 0, `0` if is 0 or `1` if is greater than 0?

Comment: I am not exactly sure...  ^^  I am fairly new to programming (only about a year under my belt), so I am not exactly sure...  Basically, I am trying to assert that a given value is positive or negative...  I am not sure how to explain it in a different way...  If I had to say which one that you provided, I would say the sign function